# Tkinter buttons and classes. How can i effectively call a function in a class through a button?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm writing this program, to draw disks using turtle. I'm doing a tkinter interface, using buttons etc. but, I don't seem to be able to execute a function inside a class through the buttons. It prompts me with this classic python error, "turtleInput() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numPressed'"

I've tried it a million times, a million ways, I just can't see the problem, maybe one of you can. I'm gonna provide you with the function inside the class and the the button ( in code of course ) hopefully you can help me out. feel free to ask questions if you don't quite understand what I am saying.

```
def turtleInput(self, numPressed):
    self.length = int(numPressed)
    self.lstColor = ["maroon","brown","red","orange","yellow",
                  "green","lightgreen","purple","blue",
                  "lightblue"]

    for i in range(0,self.length):
        self.shrink = 220
        self.shrinkLst = []
        while self.shrink > 0:
            self.shrink = self.shrink-20
            self.shrinkLst.append(self.shrink)
        self.diskCol = self.lstColor[i]
        self.turtleDisks(self.diskCol,self.shrinkLst[i])
```

now the code for the button

```
    num2= Button(root, text="2", width=3)
    num2["command"]= lambda: Disk.turtleInput(2)
    num2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=3)
```

keep in mind that I imported tkinter, turtle and everything else works fine, that is the only problem.

Comment: There's no way to tell for sure since you didn't include all the code, but if `Disk` is a class you will need to pass an *instance* of the class as the first argument to any of its methods, or else write your call as `inst.turtleInput(2)` (where `inst` is an instance of the `Disk` class). If you don't have an instance then what do you expect calling the method to do?

Comment: Disk is in fact a class, the full code is just the class disk with __init__ and that function, and the rest of the code is button num2 and num3, plus all the tkinter stuff, you know root=Tk() etc. its pretty short, thats pretty much it, im going to try what you suggested, thanks for the quick reply tho!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be referencing a `Disk` *object*, not the `Disk` *class* when referencing a function.

The solution looks like this:

```
# create instance of Disk
disk = Disk()
...
num2["command"]= lambda: disk.turtleInput(2)
```